# How to run my script on VM

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have script on my Virtual machine that i would like to run without `[]$ ./myscript`

```
[studentuser@CentosStudentSvr ~]$ myscript
```

-bash: iduser: command not found

otherwise it errors:

```
-bash: iduser: command not found
```

how can I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: what exactly do you mean "run it without `[]$ ./myscript`?

Answer (score 1):

If you type `myscript` then your shell will look in your PATH to see if it can find the command named `myscript`.  Unlike with windows your current directory is not in your path by default.

Which means you either want to:

1. add it to your path for now (munually)
2. add it to your path every time you start (edit the startup script in your folder. Which ones depends on which shell you use. Often .profile or .bashsomething)
3. Or specify the full path to the binary. E.g. `./iduser` or `/home/user229525/iduser`.

If the current directory (`.`) is already in your path then check your program.

- Is it executable? (ls -l, look for the `x` in rwx)
- If it is a script, does it start with a shebang? (e.g. is the first line `#!/usr/bin/env bash`).

Comment: Thank you very much, but didn't work and I still have to use ./myscript to work :(

Comment: What is the output from `echo $PATH`? Does it include `.` or `/home/studentuser` ? Did you try `PATH=$PATH:.` (Appending dot to the end of the path). If that works add it to your profile or other startup scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Bash looks for the "commands" in the paths enumerated in the $PATH variable. Move the script to the `/usr/bin` or another folder mentioned in the $PATH (or add the folder you have script in to the $PATH).

Also you can define an alias for the bash running `alias myscript="bash /path/to/script/myscript"`. (please verify the syntax yourself, I am not sure right now)

Comment: still need the ./ script

Comment: You are probably doing something wrong. I tested it :)